# NW.js Notification onclick dont execute on windows

Tags: javascript, notifications, nw.js

Im building a app/site using NW.js (known as node-webkit) The docs say that under linux Notifikations `onclick` event handler dont get fired, and my tests shows that aswell. but when running on windows 7 (x86 bit) the event is not fire'd ether, while it all is running on osx and under chrome + firefox
it's easy to reproduce just run a sample with somthing along the lines of:

```
var noti = new Notifikation("foo titile");
noti.onclick = function() { console.log("bar") };
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem and have been searching for an answer since yesterday night and even though I couldnt find the real answer for the "Why 'onClick()' event handler doesn't work" question, I found a workaround.

First of all, javascript is case sensitive. The appropriate usage of the 'click' event handler is 'onClick'

So the correct format is

```
//NOTE: I'm not sure if 'Notifikation' works here. Correct use of it is 'Notification'
var noti = new Notifikation("foo titile");
noti.onClick = function() { console.log("bar") };
```

Now, even though your spelling is correct, onClick event still didn't work for me on **nwjs-v0.12.2-win-x64** , Windows 8.1.

What I tried as an alternative is the **addEventListener(event, function)** method.

In this case your code would be:

```
var noti = new Notifikation("foo titile");
function clicked() { console.log("bar") };
noti.addEventListener('click',clicked);
```

I know this question is 2 months old but I just wanted to answer in case someone else would face the same problem.

Comment: thanks, the NW.js Documentation says it's `onclick` with no casing, and that worked on OSX. i guss we just have to w8 for a fix